security: SecKeychainItemSetAccessWithPassword: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct
I'm working with fastlane + GitHub Actions.
test job complete successfully, but when I'm going for build and archive project - I have error when try to archive.
this is my fastfile:
   fastlane_version '2.217.0'

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Set up the CI environment"
  lane :setup_ci_env do
    cocoapods

    sh("bundle install")
    sh("pod install")
  end

  before_all do
    setup_ci_env 
  end

  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    scan(
      workspace: "./xxx.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "xxx-iOS",
      clean: true,
      devices: ["iPhone SE (3rd generation)"],
      destination: ENV['IOS_SIMULATOR'] || "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE (3rd generation),OS=17.4"
    )
  end

  desc "Build an installable archive"
  lane :build_archive do
    build_app(
      scheme: "xxx-iOS",
      export_method: "ad-hoc",
      output_directory: "./build/outputs/ipa",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "xxx" => "xxx"
        },
        signingStyle: "manual",
        signingCertificate: "Apple Distribution"
      }
    )
  end

  desc "Deploy to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_version_number
    build_archive
    upload_to_testflight
  end

  desc "Deploy to App Store"
  lane :release do
    increment_version_number
    build_archive 
    deliver
  end
end

when I do this line locally from terminal "bundle exec fastlane build_archive" - I have successful finish.
here is my yaml code for gh actions:
  name: xxx-iOS CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - '**'
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '3.1'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd xxx
          gem install bundler
          bundle install
          pod install

      - name: Run setup_ci (before testing)
        run: |
          cd xxx
          bundle exec fastlane setup_ci_env

      - name: List available simulators
        run: xcrun simctl list

      - name: Run Tests
        run: |
          cd xxx
          IOS_SIMULATOR='platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE (3rd generation),OS=17.4' bundle exec fastlane test

  build_archive:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    needs: test
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '3.1'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd xxx
          gem install bundler
          bundle install
          pod install

      - name: Run setup_ci (before building)
        run: |
          cd xxx
          bundle exec fastlane setup_ci_env

      - name: Decrypt certificate
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 }}" > certificate_base64.txt
          echo "Decoded certificate base64 content:"
          cat certificate_base64.txt

          echo "Attempting to decode certificate base64..."
          base64 -D -i certificate_base64.txt -o DistributionCert_42DADMWRUW.p12
          
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Base64 decoding was successful."
          else
            echo "Base64 decoding failed!"
            exit 1
          fi

          if [ ! -f DistributionCert_42DADMWRUW.p12 ]; then
            echo "Certificate file is missing after base64 decoding!"
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Certificate file found."
          fi

      - name: Import certificate into login.keychain-db
        run: |
          echo "Attempting to create and unlock login.keychain-db..."
          security create-keychain -p "" /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db || echo "login.keychain-db already exists"
          security unlock-keychain -p "" /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

          echo "Attempting to import certificate to login.keychain-db..."
          security import DistributionCert_42DADMWRUW.p12 -k /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db -A -t agg -f pkcs12 -P ""

          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Certificate import successful."
          else
            echo "Certificate import failed."
            exit 1
          fi
          
      - name: List available keychains and their paths
        run: |
          echo "Listing all available keychains and their paths..."
          security list-keychains

      - name: Check if certificate is correctly installed in login.keychain-db
        run: |
          echo "Checking if the certificate is correctly installed in login.keychain-db..."
          
          output=$(security find-identity -v -p codesigning /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db)
          
          if [[ -n "$output" ]]; then
            echo "Certificate successfully installed in login.keychain."
            echo "$output"
          else
            echo "Error: Certificate is not found in login.keychain."
            exit 1
          fi
          
          echo "Checking if the private key is correctly installed in login.keychain-db..."
          output=$(security find-key -t private /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db)

          if [[ -n "$output" ]]; then
            echo "Private key successfully installed in login.keychain-db."
            echo "$output"
          else
            echo "Error: Private key is not found in login.keychain-db."
            exit 1
          fi
          
      - name: Check if login.keychain-db is accessible
        run: |
          echo "Checking if login.keychain-db is accessible..."
          if security unlock-keychain -p "" /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db; then
            echo "Successfully unlocked login.keychain-db."
          else
            echo "Failed to unlock login.keychain-db. Please check the password or keychain permissions."
            exit 1
          fi

      - name: Grant access to the keychain
        run: |
          echo "Granting access to the keychain..."
          security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k "" /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

      - name: Decrypt provisioning profile
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.BUILD_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_BASE64 }}" > provisioning_profile_base64.txt
          echo "Decoded provisioning profile base64 content:"
          cat provisioning_profile_base64.txt

          mkdir -p /Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

          echo "Attempting to decode provisioning profile base64..."
          base64 -D -i provisioning_profile_base64.txt -o "/Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/Ad_Hoc_Provisioning_Profile_for_GHA.mobileprovision"
          
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Provisioning profile decoding was successful."
          else
            echo "Provisioning profile decoding failed!"
            exit 1
          fi

          if [ ! -f "/Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/Ad_Hoc_Provisioning_Profile_for_GHA.mobileprovision" ]; then
            echo "Provisioning profile file is missing after base64 decoding!"
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Provisioning profile file found."
          fi
          
      - name: Check if provisioning profile is installed
        run: |
          echo "Checking if the provisioning profile is correctly installed..."
          security cms -D -i /Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/Ad_Hoc_Provisioning_Profile_for_GHA.mobileprovision

      - name: Build app for archive
        run: |
          echo "Building the app for archive..."
          cd xxx
          bundle exec fastlane build_archive

      - name: Upload IPA as artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: xxx.ipa
          path: ./xxx/build/outputs/ipa/*.ipa

on logs, I see what my certificate generated right, and it successfully installed to keychain. and when I open keychain - everything is ok:
echo "Attempting to create and unlock login.keychain-db..."
  security create-keychain -p "" /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db || echo "login.keychain-db already exists"
  security unlock-keychain -p "" /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
  
  echo "Attempting to import certificate to login.keychain-db..."
  security import DistributionCert_xxx.p12 -k /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db -A -t agg -f pkcs12 -P ""
  
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Certificate import successful."
  else
    echo "Certificate import failed."
    exit 1
  fi
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PATH: /Users/runner/.local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/runner/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/runner/bin:/Users/runner/.yarn/bin:/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/runner/.dotnet/tools
Attempting to create and unlock login.keychain-db...
security: SecKeychainCreate /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db: A keychain with the same name already exists.
login.keychain-db already exists
Attempting to import certificate to login.keychain-db...
1 identity imported.
Certificate import successful.

but when I try to check access to keychain - I have this error:
echo "Granting access to the keychain..."
  security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k "" /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PATH: /Users/runner/.local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/runner/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/runner/bin:/Users/runner/.yarn/bin:/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/runner/.dotnet/tools
Granting access to the keychain...
security: SecKeychainItemSetAccessWithPassword: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
keychain: "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"

But there isn't password for this keychain.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
